# invoking function inside console.log (returning still getting undefined)

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions, map-function

javascript beginner here, i have two codes (one without function invoking and one with function invoking), first one is working as i want it here it is :

```js
const numbers = [65, 44, 12, 4];
const newarray = numbers.map((myFunction)=>{
  return myFunction
})

console.log(newarray)
```

but second one i want to put everything inside a function and invoke that function in console.log, there seems to be some mistake in my code (have seen other similar but they did not return anything) ? i am returning but still getting 'undefined' here :

```js
function app(){
const numbers = [65, 44, 12, 4];
const newarray = numbers.map((myFunction)=>{
  return myFunction
})}

console.log(app())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to return at the end :)

```js
function app(){
    const numbers = [65, 44, 12, 4];
    const newarray = numbers.map((myFunction)=>{
        return myFunction;
    });
    return newarray;
}

console.log(app());
```

---

(Answering comment)

```js
function App() {
    const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    const listItems = numbers.map((number) => `<li>${number}</li>` );
    return `<ul>${listItems.join("")}</ul>`
}
console.log(App());
```

Comment: why i need to have 2 returns ? cannnot do it with just one ?

Comment: `const newarray` returns and resolves to itself, so to access it when calling `app()` you need to return that resolved variable `newarray`

Comment: Basically calling `app()` returns nothing otherwise :)

Comment: @walee No, you have two functions, and each function needs its own `return`.

Comment: @Matthew Spence if im not disturbing, i have one problem with converting a very simple react which is like this question into javascript. function App() {
  const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  const listItems = numbers.map((numbers) =>
    <li>{numbers}</li>
  );

  return (
    <ul>{listItems}</ul>
  )
}
export default App;         could you   give me example how to change this into javascript since im beginner :)

Comment: Hmm, how are you testing it? :) It may not work in older browsers, as I'm using the special ` character called a template literal https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals Instead you can do `"<li>" + number + "</li>";`

Comment: i'm using latest chrome, could you write it without console, for example innerhtml ?

Comment: Yes :) Try replacing `console.log(...)` with `document.querySelector("#yourElement").innerHTML = App()`

Answer (score 1):

You missed the bracket my dear,
it should be:
`console.log(newarray())`